# Find the number of homomorphisms between cyclic groups with infinite order

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})\simeq\mathbb{Z}/gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}$. How about $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$?

a) $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})\simeq\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, right?

b) how about $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Every element of $\mathbb{Z}$ has infinite order.  So, you can only have the trivial map.

Comment: Thanks! That is for b), right?

Comment: Yes.  For (b).  Your (a) is correct as well.